# MacDuff OpenCV -5 Bad argument in function circle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, colors

I'm trying to get the example script to work with the [MacDuff module](https://github.com/mathandy/python-macduff-colorchecker-detector)
However, it's not working out of the box as it's four years old.

This is the error:

```
D:\LearnPython\3>py macduff.py "examples/test.jpg" "result.png" > "results.csv"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "macduff.py", line 526, in <module>
    out, colorchecker = find_macbeth(argv[1])
  File "macduff.py", line 495, in find_macbeth
    found_colorchecker.size)
  File "macduff.py", line 138, in draw_colorchecker
    cv.circle(image, (x, y), radius//2, expected_color.tolist(), -1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

which points to this function:

```
def draw_colorchecker(colors, centers, image, radius):
    for observed_color, expected_color, pt in zip(colors.reshape(-1, 3),
                                                  expected_colors.reshape(-1, 3),
                                                  centers.reshape(-1, 2)):
        x, y = pt
        cv.circle(image, (x, y), radius//2, expected_color.tolist(), -1)
        cv.circle(image, (x, y), radius//4, observed_color.tolist(), -1)
    return image
```

I can't see anything wrong with that. So I'm not sure how to proceed in order to get it to work.

Comment: What is the data type of `x` and `y`? `cv.circle` accepts integer values as the center point.

Comment: Turns out it needed ints for x & y not a float and later on to reshape the array with -1